# Django HTML page not displaying the content of model, displays object(1) instead

Tags: django

I have this line of html code

```
Calculate distance {{distance}}
```

but instead of grabbing the information from the object, it instead displays

```
Calculate distance Measurements object (1)
```

This is my model

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Measurements

class MeasuremeantModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Measurements
        fields = ('distance'),
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Measurements
# Create your views here.

def calculate_distance_view(request):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Measurements)

    context = {
        'distance' : obj,
    }

    return render(request, 'measurements/main.html', context)
```

I can't figure out why it wouldn't be displaying the contents of the object
the object's distance has a value of 2000[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`distance` is a `Measurements` object, in order to render the distance of that object, you render it with:

```
Calculate distance {{ distance.distance }}
```

You can also override the `__str__` method to specify how to represent an object as text. For example:

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    distance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        'from {self.location} to {self.destination} is {self.distance}'
```